# Redux: Why is avoiding mutations such a fundamental part of using it?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm new to Redux - and I'm really trying to get the big picture of using functional programming to make unidirectional data more elegant.

The way I see it- each reducer is taking the old state, creating a new state without mutating the old state and then passing off the new state to the next reducer to do the same.

I get that not causing side effects helps us get the benefits of a unidirectional flow of data.

**I just really don't get what is so important about not mutating the old state.**

The only thing I can think of is maybe the "Time-Traveling" I've read about because, if you held on to every state, you could perform and "undo".

Question:

Are there other reasons why we don't want to mutate the old state at each step?

Answer (score 44):

Working with immutable data structures can have a positive impact on performance, if done right. In the case of React, performance often is about avoiding unnecessary re-rendering of your app, if the data did not change.

To achieve that, you need to compare the next state of your app with the current state. If the states differ: re-render. Otherwise don't.

To compare states, you need to compare the objects in the state for equality. In plain old JavaScript objects, you would need to deep compare in order to see if any property inside the objects changed.

With immutable objects, you don't need that.

```
immutableObject1 === immutableObject2
```

basically does the trick. Or if you are using a lib like Immutable.js `Immutable.is(obj1, obj2)`.

In terms of react, you could use it for the `shouldComponentUpdate` method, like the popular `PureRenderMixin` does.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return nextState !== this.state;
}
```

This function prevents re-rendering, when the state did not change.

I hope, that contributes to the reasoning behind immutable objects.

Comment: So far this is the best answer to the core of the question. Like I said - "I get that not causing side effects helps us get the benefits of a unidirectional flow of data.**I just really don't get what is so important about not mutating the old state.**"

Comment: why is this not the accepted answer? In short, if you mutate objects you cannot do the following comparison: immutableObject1 === immutableObject2. Instead you will have to perform deep compare in order to see if any property inside the objects changed.

Comment: I really don't get the argument. If I do a change in the state variable without using the reducer as a pure function the number of render calls of the component doesn't increase. e.g. https://plnkr.co/edit/ll9LufjaINxN41mkAIkr?p=preview

Comment: even putting all values inside a new variable and returning it will still work and doesn't re-render multiple times

Comment: You can also achieve similar results with the redux selectors pattern.

Comment: If you set the new object all the time, you will always re-render the part of your application where the state was used. That's why I think your answer is wrong. There are several reasons 1.

Answer (score 9):

The key of the "no-mutations" mantra is that *if you can not mutate the object, you are forced to create a new one* (with the properties of the original object plus the new ones).

To update the components when an action is dispatched, **Redux connector checks if the object is different, not if the properties have changed** (which is a lot faster), so:

- If you **create a new object**, Redux will see that the object is not the same, so **it will trigger the components updates**.
- If you **mutate** the objet that it is already in the store (adding or changing a property, for example) **Redux will not see the change**, so it will not update the components.

Comment: if your state stored an object a pritimive in it {a:5} and if you update a directly update(mutate) foo.a = 8 instead {...state, a:8 } and your component mapStateToProps checks a, then it will be updated again (rendered) but directly mutation has additionally another disadvantages such as reliability, atomic update

Comment: Redux doesn't check anything, connector between redux and react does.

Comment: @MaciejSikora connector in the sense?

Comment: @Ben react-redux

Answer (score 8):

I'm pretty new to Redux (and React.js) too, but this is what I understand from learning this stuff.

There are several reasons why immutable state is chosen over the mutable one. 
First of all, mutation tracking is pretty difficult. For example when you are using a variable in several pieces of code and the variable can be modified in each of this places, you need to handle each change and synchronize results of mutation. 
This aproach in many cases leads to bidirectional data flows. Pieces of data are flowing up and down across the functions, variables and so on. Code starts beeing polluted by `if-else` constructions that are oly responsible for handling state changes. 
When you add some asynchronous calls your state changes can be even harder to track. 
Of course we can subscribe to data events (for example `Object.observe`), but it can lead to situation that some part of application that missed change stays out of sync with other part of your program.

Immutable state helps you to implement unidirectional data flow that helps you to handle all changes. First of all data flows from top to bottom. That means all changes that were applied to the main model are pushed to the lower components. You can always be sure that the state is the same in all places of the application, because it can be changed only from one place in the code - reducers. 
There is also one thing worth of mentioning - you can reuse data in several components. State cannot be changed (a new one can be created), so it's pretty safe to use same piece of data in several places.

You can find more information about pros and cons of mutability (and about the reason why it was chosen as a main approach of Redux) here:

- [Pros and Cons of using immutability with React.js](http://reactkungfu.com/2015/08/pros-and-cons-of-using-immutability-with-react-js/)
- [React.js Conf 2015 - Immutable Data and React](https://youtu.be/I7IdS-PbEgI)
- [Immutable Data Structures and JavaScript](http://jlongster.com/Using-Immutable-Data-Structures-in-JavaScript)
- [Introduction to Immutable.js and Functional Programming Concepts](https://auth0.com/blog/2016/03/23/intro-to-immutable-js/)
- [Why immutable collections?](https://scott.mn/2014/04/27/why_immutable_collections/)

Answer (score 5):

Redux checks if the old object is the same as the new object by comparing the memory locations of the two objects. If you mutate the old object’s property inside a reducer, the “new state” and the “old state” will both point to the same object and Redux will infer that nothing has changed.

Answer (score 1):

No reasons. The are no any fundamental reasons that shouldComponentUpdate "pure render" optimization can't work with mutable state containers. This library does it, for instance.

https://github.com/Volicon/NestedReact

With immutable data the reference to the data structure itself can be used as version token. Thus, comparing the references you're comparing the versions.

With mutable data you will need to introduce (and compare) separate version tokens, which is hard to do manually but can easily be achieved with smart "observable" objects.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons.

1. Because of the history (undo/redo) feature.
2. You can use the history feature also for debugging.
3. Race conditions: Lets say you have a service that logs some state data
   after 1s. If you change the state before the service has logged the
   data the service will log the wrong data. Of course you could copy
   the state before passing it to the service, but it's easy to enforce
   this rule if you do it in a mutation/method in one place, the store, the
   single source of truth.