# Mutating Data in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am reading the [document](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data) of Reactjs about not mutating data.
I do not understand the difference between 2 pieces of code in document's example:

```
handleClick() {
  // This section is bad style and causes a bug
  const words = this.state.words;
  words.push('marklar');
  this.setState({words: words});
```

}

and:

```
handleClick() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
   words: prevState.words.concat(['marklar'])
  }));
}
```

Why the second code does not mutate the data?

Comment: In the first, you're pushing to the reference of the array. On the second, you copy the array with `concat` and does not mutate current state

Comment: `concat` returns a new array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example you have an array and are adding a new item, by using [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push?v=a) to this array.

In the second example you are creating a copy of the array, by using [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=a) and adding the item, which means you do not mutate the original array. `concat` returns a new array.

In the second example you are not mutating the original array. Not mutating state is an important principle in React and Redux.

There is a good answer [here explaining the reasons for avoiding mutation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37531909/redux-why-is-avoiding-mutations-such-a-fundamental-part-of-using-it).

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, `concat`returns a new copy of the array, hence it doesn't mutate the previous array.