# Why setState with new value is more performant than with a modified state value?

Tags: reactjs

Why snippet 1 is considered more performant than snippet 2 as said in this [article](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data)?

```
//snippet 1
handleClick() {
  this.setState(state => ({
    words: state.words.concat(['marklar'])
  }));
}

//snippet 2
handleClick() {
    const words = this.state.words;
    words.push('marklar');
    this.setState({words: words});
}
```

Comment: Just a FYI, your snippet 2 directly mutates the state, which should never be done.

Comment: Not mutating state helps React to compare structures and know when to re-render or not. 
This post will hopefully answer that for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46367264/mutating-data-in-react-js