# Resetting array and getting component rerendered

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, dplyr

I have an array which I am using to show a component. Inside that component has one dropdown. This dropdown, when changed, their values get stored in a new array which is set in the main array. There is also a Reset button which resets the state back to the previous state and should re-render the component displaying the data which was earlier before selecting anything.

[image]
When I click reset after changing a dropdown it should reset to what it was on page load. eg: Full access
The Code is as follows:

```
class EditView extends Component {
  state = {
    accessData: [],
    toBeDeleted: -1
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ accessData: this.props.accData });
  }

  resetData = () => {
    this.setState({ accessData: this.props.accData })
  };

  handleChange(value, index) {
    let dataArr = this.state.accessData;
    dataArr[index].relation = value;
    this.setState({
      accessData: dataArr
    });
  }

  postData = () => {
    const metaData ={
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'some API URL',
      page: 'page',
      data: this.state.accessData
    }
    this.props.dataSuccess(metaData); //makes a POST api call
  }

  render() {
    const { accessData } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        {accessData.map((item, index) => (
          <div>
            <DataHeading>Relation: </DataHeading>
            <Select
               defaultValue={item.relation}
               onSelect={e => this.handleChange(e, index)}
            >
              <Option value="married">Married</Option>
              <Option value="partners">Partners</Option>
              <Option value="siblings">Siblings</Option>
            </Select>
          </div>
        ))}

        <ResetButton onClick={this.resetData}>Reset</ResetButton>
        <UpdateButton onClick={this.postData}>Update</UpdateButton>
      </>
```

Problem is that the state is getting reset but not reflected in the component. Please help me out. I need a solution fast. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should not mutate the existing array but rather assign a new one, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37532497/10353987) Stack overflow post discusses why. Try the following:

```
resetData = () => {
  this.setState({ accessData: [..this.props.accData] })
};

handleChange(value, index) {
  let dataArr = [...this.state.accessData];
  dataArr[index].relation = value;
  this.setState({
    accessData: dataArr
  });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, etarhan but this doesn't solve my issue. I have attached the image of the design for better clarification. Please have a look at it.