# FlatList React Native with Redux Optimization

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

I recently came across an article about ensuring that when using FlatList with redux your `data` should be mutable.  Usually in Redux (as it says) I treat the state as immutable and return a new updated copy in my reducer.

So the article I found is an anti-pattern to what Redux suggests.  Though it says to do this because of the nature of FlatList being a `VirtualizedList`.

So my question is: "Should I be mutating data in redux that will be used in a FlatList / VirtualizedList"?

instead of doing something like:

```
case FETCH_POSTS:
   return {
     posts: [...state.posts, ...action.newPosts]
   }
```

I should do:

```
case FETCH_POSTS:
   action.newPosts.forEach((post) => state.posts.push(post))
   return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise against it. As you mentioned it's an anti-pattern and [it is for good reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37531909/redux-why-is-avoiding-mutations-such-a-fundamental-part-of-using-it). I've recently came across a bug in our app because of it. Not only it can be the cause of bugs but also makes it difficult to find them.

The react native documentation says that you should use `VirtualizedList` when working with immutable data.

Perhaps you can try a mixed approach, where you get the new state from the store and then manually mutate the state of the `FlatList`.

Comment: Yeah I suppose I can check for changes to redux state via `useEffect` and have an intermediate array that has the mutable array that I'll be passing into `data` prop of `FlatList`.  Out of curiosity, what do you use for a list of dynamic data?  Do you have a similar use case alternative to `FlatList`?

Comment: In my case I use `SectionList` with dynamic data. No issues so far. Perhaps you could give it a try and see if it works for you.