# In React, how to handle state containing arrays?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, state

I'm new to React, so I appreciate any suggestions for how to make this more idiomatic.
This is a toy example, but in the real example, my state contains an array of entities. Any change to this array of entities should trigger a re-render. Any user input or other logic may lead to the addition or deletion of multiple entities at a time.

I currently add entities to the state by copying the list of entities, appending the new item, and setting state. This also triggers a re-render, which is what I want:

```
    let nextEntities = Object.assign([], this.state.entities) as boolean[];
    nextEntities.push(val);
    this.setState({
      entities: nextEntities
    });
```

However, if I do this multiple times in a row, only the last entity gets added, because `this.state.entities` isn't up-to-date.

I even tried creating a queue of entities to add, and triggering an additional `setState` call from `setState`'s callback, but this hits a stack frame limit.
I know I could space out multiple adds in a `setTimeout` callback, but that seems dumb.
Is some usage of hooks the answer?

Here's my minimal example: https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-darkness-w1wt1?file=/src/index.tsx:0-1375

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

//My React component state has an array of entities in it
interface State {
  entities: boolean[];
}
interface Props {}

export class App extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      entities: [true, false]
    };
  }

  onClick = () => {
    console.log("onclick! current state:", this.state.entities);
    //based on user input,
    //  multiple items may get added to the array per frame
    this.addToStateList(true);
    this.addToStateList(false);
  };

  addToStateList(val: boolean) {
    let nextEntities = Object.assign([], this.state.entities) as boolean[];
    //TODO: in a non-toy example, we'd do some extra side-effects on each add here.
    nextEntities.push(val);
    this.setState({
      entities: nextEntities
    });
    console.log("just tried to push new value:", val);
  }

  render() {
    let lItems = this.state.entities.map((val: boolean, index: number) => (
      <div style={{ display: "inline" }} key={index}>
        {(val ? "true" : "false") + ", "}
      </div>
    ));
    return (
      <div onClick={this.onClick}>click to test. Current value: {lItems}</div>
    );
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

One potential suggestion I'm sure you want to provide is to batch the entities to be added, so they all get added in one `setState` call. In my real case, this is awkward because:

- entities get added or removed at different places in the code, so it's not easy to batch them together
- on addition, I need to compare the entity to be added against all the pre-existing entities (like collision detection). It's just extra cumbersome to compare (entity to be added) vs. (pre-existing entities in state + other entities to be added except for current entity being added).

Answer (score 1):

as setState is an async operation ... one possible solution is to use async-await . I am not sure if it's the best way to do it. but it surely gets the job done.

```
onClick = async () => {
    await this.addToStateList(true);
    await this.addToStateList(false);
  };
```

Comment: How much of a performance impact should I expect for peppering async/await throughout my code?

I suppose I really just want a synchronous state update operation.

Comment: i don't think there should be much of a difference

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
this.setState({
  entities: [...this.state.entities, val]
});
```

The syntax is known as a [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), if you're unfamiliar with it.

It's a good rule of thumb to [avoid mutating objects/arrays when working with React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37531909/redux-why-is-avoiding-mutations-such-a-fundamental-part-of-using-it). So, if your app gets complex, there is a very handy library, called [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper).

Comment: I see the spread operator is less cumbersome than copying the list, but if I add `val1` and `val2` right after one another, I believe that still only `val2`'s addition will occur, unless I use async-await as suggested by @Mohammad Faisal's answer.

Comment: You can always utilize the [second argument](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) of `setState`. It is a callback which fires when the state has been updated, like this. `this.setState({entities: [...this.state.entities, val]}, () => {/* here, you're guaranteed to have the updated state  */})`

Comment: unfortunately I tried that, but I run into stack frame limits if I try to add more than 4 items at a time. I wish it was that easy.